# Does $\frac{\cos(z^3)}{z-1}$ admits anti-derivative in $\Bbb{C}-\{1\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find out if $\frac{\cos(z^3)}{z-1}$ admits anti-derivative in $\Bbb{C}-\{1\}$. I thought about using the following theorem:

> [image]

I tried to find a curve $\gamma$ to use the $(i)\iff (ii)$ equivalence but this didn't end up very well. I also tried to find two paths with the same endpoints to use $(i)\iff (iii)$ but it also didn't end up well. What should I do here?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\cos(z^3)-\cos1}{z-1}$ is an entire function.

Answer (score 2):

By Residue Theorem $\int_{|z-1|=1} \frac {\cos(z^{3})} {z-1}=2\pi i \cos (1) \neq 0$. Hence there is no anti-derivative.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)$ is an entire function, then so is $\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$ if we define it as $f’(a)$ when $z=a.$

Entire functions have antiderivatives.

So $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ has an anti-derivative if and only if $\frac{f(a)}{z-a}$ has an anti-derivative.

---

More generally, this is true if, instead of “entire,” we have $f$ analytic in some simply-connected neighborhood of $a.$